# Rails: Failed to authenticate with Slack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slack

Thank you so much to help me in advance. I'm working on an application where people authenticate with Slack and it send a notification to their workspace at the same time the contents generated automatically.

But oauth error occurs:

```
OAuth Error: Invalid client_id parameter
```

URL is like below:

```
https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXX&scope=bot%2Cusers%3Aread.email%2Ccommands%2Cusers%3Aread&state=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&tracked=1
```

I had a same issue when trying to build with `omniauth_slack` gem.

**app/views/home/index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Slack", slack_activate_path %>
```

**app/controllers/slack_controller.rb**

```
class SlackController < ApplicationController
  def activate
    oauth_state = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    uri = URI('https://slack.com/oauth/authorize')
    uri.query = {
      client_id: Rails.application.credentials[:slack][:client_id],
      scope: 'bot,users:read.email,commands,users:read',
      state: oauth_state,
    }.to_query

    redirect_to uri.to_s
  end

  def callback
  end
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'

  match '/slack/activate', to: 'slack#activate', via: 'get'
  match '/slack/callback', to: 'slack#callback', via: 'get'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have mistyped `client_id` on credentials.
This requires not `.`.